# В django allauth перестала работать oauth vkontakte

Tags: django, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, oauth

В django allauth перестала работать oauth vkontakte.
По всей видимости это связано с тем, что VK с 2018 года требует указывать версию API.

В каком месте библиотеки allauth нужно внести изменения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас точно последняя версия библиотеки?

Вижу, что тут версия указывается:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/vk/views.py

Comment: Да, действительно в репозитории этот fix есть, а `pip install` устанавливает старую версию без фикса. В этом была проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавлю лишь. что для решения пришлось скачать себе с github библиотеку allauth (положить папку allauth в корень своего проекта), т.к. pip install устанавливал версию allauth в которой этого fix нет.
(возможно, это потомучто у меня старая верcия django==1.11)